# Hartshorne Exercise 1.1.10: Give an example of a noetherian topological space of infinite dimensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne Exercise 1.1.10: Give an example of a noetherian topological space of infinite dimensions.

I'm baffled by why such space can exist. Instincts told me that I shouldn't take the Spec of any Noetherian ring because then prime ideals have finite height, which makes the dimension of the Spec to be finite as well. 
But this still doesn't make sense for the following reason: by part $(a)$, we know that $X$ is a topological space which is covered by a family of open subsets $\{U_i\}$, then $\dim X = \sup \dim U_i$. $X$ by being a Noetherian topological space, is campact and thus we can have a finite sub-cover of the cover, and $\dim X = \max U_j$, $j \in J$ where $J$ is a finite index set. Since each $U_j$ is then finite dimensional space, we thus have $\dim X$ in finite.

Am I missing something? What would be an example?

Comment: This is true if you have an open cover that doesn't require the open set $X$.  But, some spaces have no covers that don't include the whole space.

Comment: There are Noetherian rings of infinite Krull dimension. Consequently, the spectra of such rings also have infinite dimension as topological spaces.

Answer (score 6):

An example of such a space would be the unit interval where you make the closed intervals $\left[ \frac{1}{n}, 1 \right]$ the closed sets.

Comment: Thank you! But is $X$ still a topological space?

Comment: @octoberbear The intervals I defined are closed under intersections and finite unions.  Thus they define a topology.

Comment: Thanks! But if your underlying set is the unit interval, if must satisfy the topology axioms to become a topological space, which means we also need $Ø$ and $X$ to be in the topology.

Comment: @octoberbear Yes, but you can add those in at no extra cost.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @octoberbear Just take the sets I described and add in both $\emptyset$ and $X$.  Unions and intersections still work out.

Answer (score 6):

Similarly take $\mathbb{N}$ with the topology where the closed sets are {1,2,...,n} for any n.

Answer (score 1):

> **prime ideals have finite height, which makes the dimension of the Spec to be finite as well**

This is not true, because you could find longer and longer chains of prime ideals, each becoming stationary after finitely many steps but there is no global bound before which each and every one of them becomes stationary.

For the example see [Stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109732/noetherian-ring-with-infinite-krull-dimension-nagatas-example)