# Every prime ideal has finite height in a Noetherian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

In Corollary 11.12 of Atiyah-Macdonald, it says that in a Noetherian ring every prime ideal has finite height. It seems to come directly from Proposition 11.10, which says if $A$ is a Noetherian local ring, $\dim A \leq d(A)$, where $d(A)$ is the degree of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, hence finite. It seems like from that proposition you can only conclude that any prime ideal in a Noetherian **local** ring has finite height. I don't see how you can reach Corollary 11.12.

Comment: If you believe in Corollary 11.11, then recall that the height of a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ equals $\dim A_{\mathfrak p}$ (which is a noetherian local ring).

Comment: How would a chain of ideals establishing infinite height not violate the ascending chain condition?  (asks a non-algebraist)

Comment: @EricTowers: You don't need an infinite ascending chain to get infinite height, just arbitrarily long finite chains.

Comment: @EricTowers Also, the height of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is the supremum of lengths of chains of prime ideals contained in $\mathfrak{p}$, so the height of a prime ideal has something to do with the descending chain condition, not the ascending chain condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should be careful not to confuse the height of an ideal with the Krull dimension of the ring. A famous example of Nagata shows that a Noetherian ring can indeed have infinite Krull dimension, precisely because it has prime ideals which have arbitrarily large height. 
See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109732/noetherian-ring-with-infinite-krull-dimension-nagatas-example) for details of Nagata's example.

However, the height of any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in a Noetherian ring $R$ can still never be infinite.  To see this, as the comments mention, one can combine Proposition 11.10 in Atiyah-Macdonald with the fact that $\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak{p}=\dim R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, which follows from their Corollary 3.13, to conclude that $\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak{p}$ is finite.