# Are Noetherian commutative rings finitely generated algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I wonder if every Noetherian commutative ring is a finitely generated algebra over some PID.

Has this problem been proved or disproved?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Counterexamples exist. A finitely generated algebra over a PID has finite Krull dimension, but there are [Noetherian rings with infinite Krull dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109732/noetherian-ring-with-infinite-krull-dimension-nagatas-example).

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really a clever way.