# Is there a Noetherian ring which satisfies this property?

Tags: ring-theory, noetherian

Does there exist a Noetherian ring which has arbitrarily large finite strictly increasing sequences of ideals? I know that a Noetherian ring can't have infinite strictly increasing sequences of ideals, by definition, but what about arbitrarily large finite ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, even $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies this. For each $n$:

$(2^{n+1})\subseteq (2^n)\subseteq (2^{n-1})\subseteq...\subseteq (2)$

And all the inclusions are proper.

A more interesting question is can there be a Noetherian ring of infinite dimension, i.e which has aribitrary long increasing finite sequences of **prime** ideals. This is also possible, see here:

[Noetherian ring with infinite Krull dimension (Nagata's example).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109732/noetherian-ring-with-infinite-krull-dimension-nagatas-example)